# Spring security CSRF CORS

Tags: angularjs, rest, spring-security, cors, csrf

**Problem Statement:** I have some restful APIs which are CSRF protected using spring security. Also, these APIs will be accessed from **different Origin/domain by Angular WEB UI**. I don't need Spring Authentication as authentication is handled by Siteminder.

**Approach:**
I followed this link from from Dave Syer for CSRF protection : [The Login Page: Angular JS and Spring Security Part II](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/12/the-login-page-angular-js-and-spring-security-part-ii) which is **working perfectly except one issue (Below).**

**Issue**: This code work perfectly fine when my angular html client accessing the RESTful APIs on the same origin/domain; but when I try to access the same APIs from a different origin, getting an error 403 - Access Forbidden - CSRF token error.

Approach That I tried so far by extending your example:

1. Added a CORS filter - [Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

   ```
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
   response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with");
   ```

No Luck on the above.

Please suggest if I need to do anything else to make it work.

Thanks,
Suman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSRF and CORS are not the same thing. You probably have the CORS part sorted now, but you need to add a CSRF token to any POST/PUT/DELETE requests. Spring Security sends the token in a header in the blog series you quoted and Angular picks it up from there (you need to add a few lines of code to get that working).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dave Syer ! It worked after adding few lines of angular code for the client from here : [link]https://github.com/pasupulaphani/angular-csrf-cross-domain. Also, added Access-Control-Allow-Headers:origin, content-type , X-CSRF-TOKEN in CORS filter to make accessible from a different origin. 
Access-Control-Request-Method:POST

Comment: can you please post what did you add to the angularjs app in order to make it run? Thank you!

Comment: See code here: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/blob/master/single/src/main/java/demo/UiApplication.java#L65